# Implementing generic stack in c++

Tags: c++, generics, boost, stl, stack

I am working on implementing a generic stack data strucuture using STL and boost library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stack>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Stack{
    private:
        std::stack<boost::any> st;
    public:
        bool empty();
        int size();
        boost::any top();
        void push(boost::any ele);
        void pop();
};

bool Stack::empty(){
    return st.empty();
}

int Stack::size(){
    return st.size();
}

boost::any Stack::top(){
    return st.top();
}

void Stack::push(boost::any e){
    st.push(e);
}

void Stack::pop(){
    st.pop();
}

int main(){
    Stack st;
    int a = 10;
    st.push(a);
    int b = boost::any_cast<int>(st.top());
    float c = 10.0;
    st.push(c);

}
```

Although it's working perfectly but I want to avoid explicit typecast while retrieving an item from the stack. I want that somehow stack should return item after typecasting it automatically based on the item's type.

I am planning to maintain a hashmap with the stack which could store type information of every element and could be used to type cast each item before returning it, but I am not able to write this as code. Please suggest me some possible ways.

Comment: make your stack be a template class like the rest of stl, and probably you will solve your task without need of boost.any.

Comment: @user3159253: I think perhaps the OP wants to be able to put items of different types on the same stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot *automatically* cast to the right type; then the return type of your `top()` function would depend on whatever happens at runtime.  So, what return type would you give your `top()` function at compile time?  The best you can do is something like

```
template <typename T>
T top()
{
  return boost::any_cast<T>(stack.top());
}
```

**Edit**: As for your comment – no, you cannot use `auto` return type to get the behavior you hope, because the compiler will deduce what type `auto` represents *at compile time* – and it deduces what you return: a `boost::any`. Anything more specific can only be known at runtime.

Comment: @sv_jan5 no. You need to realize C++ is not a dynamically typed language (`auto` is not like `dynamic` in C#, but like `var` in C#)

Comment: @sehe Thanks, I added that to my answer.

Comment: Technically, you _can_ use `auto` as the return type (and it will deduce `boost::any`)

Comment: @sehe You're absolutely right, of course. Clarified.

Comment: Without using templates is possible to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @sv_jan5 No, at least not in a good way. You could write different methods `Foo topFoo()`, `Bar topBar()` and so on, but what would be the point?